# Does English have words to describe the lowest rank member of society?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, translation, class-based-usage

For example, in Indonesia we have "rakyat". In English we may have citizen but the word actually has power connotation rather than powerless connotation.

Another word is peasant. But that seems to mean those living in village rather than the lowest ranking  people in society.

Here, when I say *lowest rank*, I mean lowest rank in political power. Most of us, for example, are just "people" no matter how rich we are.

So what's the word for the lowest rank member in English?

Comment: I think that there is a notional assent in the UK (and certainly a written one in the US) that, as stated by the English-born William Penn “all men are equal under God”. Judaism and Christianity teach this. Though not everyone in the West seeks to value others as highly as himself.

Comment: I think that peasant can be used effectively to mean people on the lowest rung of society without implying that they live in a village. This would be a slightly pejorative use of the word.

Comment: What are you saying _Rakyat_ is the equivalent of? _Bank Rakyat Indonesia_ translates to _People's Bank of Indonesia_.

Comment: You should be careful with “rank”. It can be a sensitive term for many.

Comment: The unspoken assumption that there is a single word for "the lowest rank member in English" is incorrect. This question as currently stated is attracting a long list of word suggestions, and needs to be reworded. Until this happens it should be closed "not constructive".

Comment: `"I know my place."` http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p00hhrwl

Comment: In many countries there are people with less political power than citizens, such as non-citizens and refugees.

Comment: 'Lower class', though it is somewhat about money in the US, is also about political power (unless you count unions as lower class political organizatinos).

Comment: A small correction. The word 'Rakyat' in Indonesian simply means "The People", and does not carry the connotation of being powerless or the lowest ranked member of society. Adding a qualifier "Jelata" to transform it into "Rakyat jelata" would be more appropriate, since it connotes powerless people.

Comment: Too late to add an answer, but also consider "indigent" and "pauper". "Pauper" is not typically used when speaking of modern people, though. As @lunchmeat317 noted "peon" might be best, though it is really a pejorative and can make the speaker sound snobbish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might consider using the word **[peon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peon)**. I believe that it has the meaning you seek; additionally, it also carries the connotation you're looking for. Finally, it's informal enough to be understood in everyday speech.

Answer (score 19):

The word *pleb* can be used to describe very lowly people in political terms.

Comment: or ploretar? ploretariat?

Comment: @JimThio: I think you mean "proletariat".

Comment: As an informal solution, I like this real well.

Comment: @tylerharms No, he means _pleb_, a common abbreviation of _plebeian_ (from the latin _plebs, plebis_). Aka, "common people." This has a bit of a derogatory connotation in many English speaking countries.

Comment: In America, a *pleb* is a new pledge at a college fraternity.

Comment: @SamWhited - tylerharms was talking to Jim Thio (commenter), not Jez (answerer). Jim Thio posted 2 suggestions that were misspellings of "proletariat."

Comment: @roviuser Wow... somehow I completely missed that. Thanks! (Sorry @tylerharms)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this wholeheartedly in British English. It's muddied by the fact that we use the word for someone idiotic. Better words that are solely focused on social status would be peasant, serf or peon. Check the wikipedia article for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plebs

Answer (score 14):

Western society does not have explicit castes, and even notional/nominal class is tied now more to education and profession than to birth. In fact, it is more than a little bit politically incorrect to talk about these things, because it condemns people for things beyond their own control.

If you are talking about somebody who’s nobody special, you might try for [an *average Joe* or *Joe Everyman*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everyman).  This is a bit less unkind than calling a member of the *masses* a *“nobody”*.

Moving into strictly pejorative territory now,
per the OED, a *lowlife* (irregular plural *lowlifes* instead of **lowlives*) is “a coarse, vulgar, or no-good person.”  Inspecting a thesaurus will lead to [countless synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/lowlife) of such *good-for-nothings* and *scoundrels*.

Similar queries can be constructed if you are more interested in focusing on them as [*uneducated* and *uncultured know-nothings*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/uneducated?s=t) on the one hand, or on the other, as the [*poor unfortunates*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pauper?s=t) and related *do-nothings* who make up the unproductive non-working class, sometimes called the permanent underclass.  In earlier times, and perhaps even now, these unscrupulous cads were also called *stick-at-nothing*, for which the OED gives the example of “a false, lying, swindling, underhand, **stick-at-nothing** brute.”

If there is any connection to be found here amongst these many pejoratives, it is the “nothingness” link connecting *good-for-nothing*, *do-nothing*, *know-nothing*, and *stick-at-nothing*.

Comment: While you have a point, the recent row over 'plebs' in the UK shows how deep the class divides are.  Class may not be caste, but 'serf' and 'pleb' are not very pejorative and denote the least powerful and broadest spectrum of society.

Comment: @AkberChoudhry In America, a *pleb* is merely a nickname for someone pledging to a college fraternity or sorority. [Google for *pleb fraternity*](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=pleb+fraternity&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 11):

The lowest-ranking person in society might be a [serf](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serf):-

> a person in a condition of servitude, required to render services to a lord, commonly attached to the lord's land and transferred with it from one owner to another.

or perhaps a [churl](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/churl):-

> a. A ceorl.
>   b. A medieval English peasant.

Slightly higher in the pecking order would be a [villein](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/villein):-

> One of a class of feudal serfs who held the legal status of freemen in their dealings with all people except their lord.

The precise gradations and the names used would depend on which part of the world we are discussing, and the historical time. In modern times, the lowest of the low would probably be a [chav](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chav):-

> a young lower-class person typified by brash and loutish behaviour

Moving over to India, we might find an [untouchable](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/untouchable):-

> Hinduism.  the former name given to a member of a lower caste in India whose touch was believed to defile a high-caste Hindu; Harijan.

Comment: Both _churl_ and _villein_ seem archaic and nearly unusable. And _chav_ would be lost on most AmE speakers. The closest words we have to _chav_ in AmE are probably _white trash_ or _redneck_.

Comment: @tylerharms, _churl_ and _villein_ are still in use as _churlish_ and _villain_ (I'm told it's from the Normans using these words as terms of abuse). Perhaps you'd like to post your suggestions as answers; the question doesn't appear to have any limit as to time or place.

Comment: If there's no limit to time or place, then why aren't there all sorts of answers for Old Church Slavonic?

Comment: I'd go with "serf".

Comment: @Brian Hooper: Our _villain_ implies something negative and not necessarily associated with class while 11th-century usage of _villein_ deals specifically with class. For some time this has been the case. Orlando remarks to this effect in _As You Like It_: "he is thrice a villain that says such a father begot villeins". Maybe villains are at the bottom of society, but not on account of class.

Comment: I agree that churl and villain now have negative connotations that don't fit the meaning sought by the OP. "Serf" and "pleb", on the other hand, while they had more specific meanings at one time, that may not fit the desired meaning, now are often used simply to mean "very low-status person."

Comment: +1 for serf. The rest, as already stated, seem archaic.

Comment: It seems to me villain implies higher status. The bad guy in a James Bond movie is the villain, the guy who stole your wallet is just a common criminal.

Comment: Note the spelling difference -- _villain_ (bad guy) vs. _villein_ (medieval serf).

Answer (score 6):

There are many words to describe the lowest class of society. The ones that haven't been mention yet are: [*Underclass*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underclass) and [*Working poor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_poor).

Comment: Or [the great unwashed](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+great+unwashed).

Comment: I did mention *underclass* in [my own earlier answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105486), but perhaps you missed it; it is somewhat buried.  Also, the ***working* poor** are a significant step up from the ***non-working* poor**, since the working ones are productive members of society while the non-working ones are not.

Answer (score 2):

What about 'dregs of society'?

Comment: In the US, a homeless alcoholic (in theory) has the same rights to vote, serve in a jury, petition Congress, practice religion, speak, etc, as a Billionaire.

Answer (score 2):

'pleb' and 'serf' are good approximations.

For a term that is not archaic, is neither pejorative nor exalting, how about 'hoi-polloi'?

Comment: Actually I believe *hoi-polloi* does have pejorative connotations.

Comment: Yes, on second thought, agreed.  Maybe, just its anglicized version - 'the masses'.

Comment: At least as derogatory is _"the great unwashed", "the herd", rabble_ and _riffraff_ (all collective designations) and _prole, grunt_ and _knuckle-dragger_ (epithets applied to individuals).

Answer (score 1):

Not so much, in terms of "rank", but another useful term that I can think of is `"Social Pariah"` from:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pariah

> noun
>   1. an outcast.
>   2. any person or animal that is generally despised or avoided.
>   3. (initial capital letter) a member of a low caste in southern India and Burma.

It's sometimes used colloquially as:

> "No-one ever asked Tom for a beer, he was the social pariah in the office."

Answer (score 1):

[*Commoner*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/commoner):

> An ordinary person, without rank or title.

Answer (score 1):

In a society without a rank structure, it's hard to come up with a word for the lowest rank.

However, there is this idiom: **cog in the machine**.

The phrase is used to describe an insignifcant or unimportant person, often made to feel dehumanized. [One website](http://esl.about.com/library/glossary/bldef_196.htm) explains how the expression refers to "an unimportant part of a large enterprise; an exchangeable piece of equipment" that's "used in a very negative sense when expressing dissatisfaction with one's position."  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cog+in+the+wheel) defines it as: *One who holds a minor but necessary post in a large organization*.

Answer (score 0):

Use **mudsill**. Here are the references: [link1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mudsill), [link2](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mudsill&allowed_in_frame=0)

Use **heel**, but I suspect it's really rare. [link3](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=heel&allowed_in_frame=0)

Use **plebeian**. [link4](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plebeian&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: Is this a common word?

Comment: Yes, I believe.

Comment: Mudsill is extremely rare, heel is just a jerk (says nothing about status) and plebeian is heard but not as common as peasant or commoner.

Comment: Never heard of mudsill. (I'm a native English speaker.) Agree with Mitch that heel means something negative about character / behavior, and doesn't carry information about social status to me.

Answer (score 0):

In some (but apparently not all) Western countries, we think everyone is equal.  But in fact there are people with less political rank than citizens.  They are called prisoners.  Prisoners often do not have the right to vote or participate in juries.  The civil liberties (freedom of speech, association, privacy, etc.) of prisoners are often more limited than those enjoyed by citizens.

Comment: This is not general for the west. It only applies to the US.

Answer (score 0):

*[Nonperson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonperson)* comes to mind, although it is supposed to mean someone who is so low that they actually fall out of society altogether.

Comment: A _non-person_ is one who is actively ostracized by being shunned by their community and/or being forced out of their job, home, etc. It was a familiar method of reining in dissidents during the heyday of Soviet and Far Eastern communist regimes, but has also been employed to varying extents in most Western countries at one time or another (for instance, recall how McCarthyite blacklisting was used to cow left-leaning film studios and actors in the 1950s, or (worse still) how Germany's jews were treated after 1933). It's not so much a question of _falling_ out of society as being _pushed_ out.